# Get access to data in dynamic table using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

Below code works and fills out two forms which is required to get to the table on this page: https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/resultatside

Once the forms are filled out the table shows an overview over difference insurance firms and how much you will pay yearly for car insurance. So a comparison service. I need to scrape this overview once a week.

I am unsure how to do this. I know how to use BS4 for scraping, but I need the firm names as well, and not only the information, and this is not available by inspecting the website in Chrome. If I dive into 
the network and look into XHR i find this link

```
https://forsikringsguiden.dk/signalr/poll?transport=longPolling&messageId=d-D7589F50-A%2C0%7C9%2C0%7C_%2C1%7C%3A%2C0&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=fUYa3MT52oKf77Y6yU1sLnXiVzPw2CD4XgA8x50EfifJlz8XTPjBeP0klHUKt2uXmnisqO0KLk3fCb5bjOZ8k%2FeJl8zaXAgtRIALW9rzMF%2F8L7Pk3MOYwPRY4md1sDk5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22insuranceofferrequesthub%22%7D%5D&tid=9&_=1572505813840
```

This shows me all the data I need, but I cannot navigate to this page in selenium.

How do I tackle this problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

# enable browser logging
d = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
d['loggingPrefs'] = { 'browser':'ALL' } 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities = d, options=chrome_options)
driver.fullscreen_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,1)

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/manuel")

#time.sleep(5)

#remove cookie bar
driver.find_element_by_id('cookieBarAccept').click()        

maerke = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_carSelectedMake"]/a').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen1_search"]').send_keys("Hyundai")
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()


model = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen2"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen3_search"]').send_keys("i30")
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250)")         

aargang = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen4"]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen5_search"]').send_keys("2009")
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250)") 

motor_str = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen6"]/a').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen7_search"]').send_keys("1,6")
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()


variant = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen8"]').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="s2id_autogen9_search"]').send_keys("1,6 CRDi 116HK 5d")
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250)")         

godkend_oplysninger = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[4]/form/div[6]/div/button').click()


#Om dig siden

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/omdig")     

alder = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/input')))
alder.send_keys("50")

adresse = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="adresse-autocomplete"]')))
adresse.send_keys("Havevang 8, 3. th, 4300 Holbæk", Keys.ENTER)

aar = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/input')))
aar.send_keys("10")

driver.execute_script("scrollBy(0,250)")

#Antal skader
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[3]/div/div/div[2]').click()
wait
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[11]/ul/li[3]').click()
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()
time.sleep(1)

#skade 1
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]').click()
wait
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[12]/ul/li[5]').click()
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()
time.sleep(1)


#skade 2
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]').click()
wait
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[13]/ul/li[3]').click()
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select2-drop"]').click()
time.sleep(1)


find_daekning = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/button').click()
```

EDIT:
I added this to my code using Selenium:

```
##### Get Data #####

driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/resultatside") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait
res_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]')

res = [x.text for x  in res_element]

print(res, "\n")
```

But it doesn't get me the numbers, just some of the text. 
Here the result

```
['Sortér efter: Forklaring\nGå til selskab\nDin dækning\nkr./år -\nMed
 samlerabat kr./år\nSelvrisiko\nSe detaljer\nSammenlign\nGå til selskab\nDin dækning\nkr./år -\nMed samlerabat kr./år\nSelvrisiko
\nSe detaljer\nSammenlign\nGå til selskab\nDin dækning\nkr./år -
\nMed samlerabat kr./år\nSelvrisiko\nSe detaljer\nSammenlign\n
```

Comment: Can you give 2-3 examples of firm names in the overview table?

Comment: Here I inspect one of the companies image, and I see that they all have a companyID. The first company, Alka, has the ID 25, same as the end of the .svg image. I'm not sure if selenium has a data scraping function, like BS4. <div class="list-item-brand" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/api/img/companies/'+insuranceMatch.companyId+'.svg)'}" style="background-image: url(&quot;/api/img/companies/25.svg&quot;);">
                                        <!-- <img ng-src="/api/img/companies/{{insuranceMatch.companyId}}.svg">-->
                                    </div>

Comment: Some company names are Alka, FDM, PenSam, Tryg etc.

Comment: Added some of my experimental code.

Comment: Got it; and can you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: creating a new question, more relevant as I figured this part out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58643748/get-certain-elements-of-html-using-selenium