# Get certain elements of HTML using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The reason why I'm using selenium is, that I navigate to the URL filling out several forms, and getting to a page that gives me an overview over insurance prices that are calculated based on certain information.

Therefore I need to continue using Selenium to scrape the site as well.

```html
<div class="list-item-pricing">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="tableCell">
            <div class="main-price" basicprice="3459">
                <h2 class="nmt nmb"><small>kr./år</small> <span ng-show="insuranceMatch.basicprice < 999999" class="ng-binding">3,459​</span><span ng-show="insuranceMatch.basicprice >= 999999" class="ng-hide">-</span></h2>
                <div class="discount-price" discountedprice="2958">
                    <h4 class="nmt nmb ng-binding"><small>Med samlerabat kr./år</small> 2,958​</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="deductible-price" selvrisiko="6324">
                    <h4 class="nmt nmb ng-binding"><small>Selvrisiko</small> 6,324​</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code:

```
resultatside = driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/resultatside")
def get_car_insurance(url):          
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    wait
    res_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="listInsurances"]/div[10]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div')

    res = res_element.get_attribute("ng-binding")
    #res = [x.text for x  in res_element]

    return res        

print(get_car_insurance(resultatside))
```

In my code I try to get the first one, basicprice, without any luck. I cannot use BS4 here.

I would like the output to be:
The basic price: 3,459
The discounted price: 2,958
The selvrisiko: 6,324

EDIT:

If needed, here's the entire HTML for one row of elements. I have 17 of these.

```html
<div ng-repeat="insuranceMatch in insuranceMatches" isotope-item="" class="kindling ng-scope has-no-membership isotope-item" ng-class="(insuranceMatch.hasmemberrequirements) ? 'has-membership' : 'has-no-membership'" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
    <div class="list-item enlarge-main">
        <div class="panel default small">
            <!--<div class="loading-indicator" ng-show="insuranceMatch.isLoading">
                <img src="app/img/spinner.gif" />
            </div>-->
            <div class="containerLoaderProduct ng-hide" ng-show="insuranceMatch.isLoading"><div class="loader"></div></div>
            <!--<div class="list-item-row line1">-->
            <div class="list-item-company ng-hide" ng-click="openCompanyPopup($index)" ng-hide="insuranceMatch.gotoCompanyWithoutData">
                <div class="list-item-brand" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/api/img/companies/'+insuranceMatch.companyId+'.svg)'}" style="background-image: url(&quot;/api/img/companies/18.svg&quot;);">
                    <!-- <img ng-src="/api/img/companies/{{insuranceMatch.companyId}}.svg">-->
                </div>
                <div class="go-to-company">Gå til selskab</div>
            </div>
            <form id="form9" name="form9" action="/" method="post" target="_blank" ng-click="gotoCompanyWithoutData($index,insuranceMatch.companycontacturl)" ng-show="insuranceMatch.gotoCompanyWithoutData" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
                <div class="list-item-company">
                    <div class="list-item-brand" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/api/img/companies/'+insuranceMatch.companyId+'.svg)'}" style="background-image: url(&quot;/api/img/companies/18.svg&quot;);">
                    </div>
                    <div class="go-to-company">Gå til selskab</div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div class="list-item-information">

                <div class="list-item-coverage">
                    <div class="containerInner">
                        <div class="yourCoverageText">Din dækning</div><div class="star-ratings ng-isolate-scope" star-rating="" stars="insuranceMatch.stars" coveragequality="9303.697368421055">
                            <!-- ngRepeat: star in stars --><span ng-repeat="star in stars" class="rating-icon ng-scope">
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_c rating-icon-bg invisible" ng-class="{'invisible': star.half || star.full}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_b rating-icon-half" ng-class="{visible: star.half}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_a rating-icon-full visible" ng-class="{visible: star.full}"></i>
                            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: star in stars --><span ng-repeat="star in stars" class="rating-icon ng-scope">
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_c rating-icon-bg invisible" ng-class="{'invisible': star.half || star.full}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_b rating-icon-half" ng-class="{visible: star.half}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_a rating-icon-full visible" ng-class="{visible: star.full}"></i>
                            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: star in stars --><span ng-repeat="star in stars" class="rating-icon ng-scope">
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_c rating-icon-bg invisible" ng-class="{'invisible': star.half || star.full}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_b rating-icon-half" ng-class="{visible: star.half}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_a rating-icon-full visible" ng-class="{visible: star.full}"></i>
                            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: star in stars --><span ng-repeat="star in stars" class="rating-icon ng-scope">
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_c rating-icon-bg invisible" ng-class="{'invisible': star.half || star.full}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_b rating-icon-half" ng-class="{visible: star.half}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_a rating-icon-full visible" ng-class="{visible: star.full}"></i>
                            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: star in stars --><span ng-repeat="star in stars" class="rating-icon ng-scope">
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_c rating-icon-bg invisible" ng-class="{'invisible': star.half || star.full}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_b rating-icon-half" ng-class="{visible: star.half}"></i>
                                <i class="fg-icon-int_star_a rating-icon-full visible" ng-class="{visible: star.full}"></i>
                            </span><!-- end ngRepeat: star in stars -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="list-item-insurance">
                    <div class="containerInner">
                        <ul class="inline-list list-item-addons">
                            <li class="addon-icon active" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[0].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_kasko" tooltipnew="Kasko dækker: skader på bilen,&nbsp;skader på bilens tilbehør, tyveri og&nbsp;retshjælp" tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="addon-icon" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[1].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_friskade" tooltipnew="Friskade betyder, at prisen på forsikringen ikke stiger ved skader, og der ikke skal betales selvrisiko ved fx tyveri, brand, nedstyrtning af ting på bilen og seriehærværk. Læs om den konkrete dækning hos det enkelte selskab på selskabets detaljeside eller på sammenligningssiden." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="addon-icon" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[2].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_udvidetglas" tooltipnew="Udvidet glas betyder, at prisen på forsikringen ikke stiger, og der ikke skal betales fuld selvrisiko ved skader på bilens glas.&nbsp;Læs om den konkrete dækning hos det enkelte selskab på selskabets detaljeside eller på sammenligningssiden." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true" tooltipnew-active="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="addon-icon" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[3].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_forerdaekning" tooltipnew="Førerdækning dækker personskader, hvis føreren af bilen kommer til skade i forbindelse med et færdselsuheld.&nbsp;Læs om den konkrete dækning hos det enkelte selskab på selskabets detaljeside eller på sammenligningssiden." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="addon-icon" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[4].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_vejhjaelp" tooltipnew="Vejhjælp dækker som udgangspunkt følgende:&nbsp;bugsering, starthjælp, fritrækning, o.lign. Læs om den konkrete dækning hos det enkelte selskab på selskabets detaljeside eller på sammenligningssiden." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></i></li>
                            <li class="addon-icon" ng-class="{true: 'active'}[insuranceMatch.addtionalOptions[5].chosen]"><i class="fg fg-icon-icon_bil_fastpraemie" tooltipnew="Fastpris betyder, at forsikringens pris ikke automatisk stiger ved en skade." tooltip-placement="right" tooltip-append-to-body="true"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item-pricing">
                <div class="table">
                    <div class="tableCell">
                        <div class="main-price" basicprice="3459">
                            <h2 class="nmt nmb"><small>kr./år</small> <span ng-show="insuranceMatch.basicprice < 999999" class="ng-binding">3,459​</span><span ng-show="insuranceMatch.basicprice >= 999999" class="ng-hide">-</span></h2>
                            <div class="discount-price" discountedprice="2958">
                                <h4 class="nmt nmb ng-binding"><small>Med samlerabat kr./år</small> 2,958​</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="deductible-price" selvrisiko="6324">
                                <h4 class="nmt nmb ng-binding"><small>Selvrisiko</small> 6,324​</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list-item-actions">
                <div class="containerButtonDetails">
                    <button type="submit" class="button primary inverse expand" ng-click="goToDetails(insuranceMatch.companyId, insuranceMatch.produktId, insuranceMatch.resultid)" ng-class="{'disabled': insurancematch.isloading}">Se detaljer</button>
                </div>
                <div class="containerButtonCompare">
                    <button ng-hide="insuranceMatch.addToComparison" class="button compare expand" ng-click="addToComparison($index)" ng-class="{'active': insuranceMatch.addToComparison}">
                        <span ng-hide="insuranceMatch.addToComparison" class="">Sammenlign</span>
                    </button>
                    <div ng-show="insuranceMatch.addToComparison" class="button compare expand ng-hide" ng-class="{'active': insuranceMatch.addToComparison}">
                        <span class="closeIconSmallWhite" ng-click="addToComparison($index)"></span>
                        <span ng-show="addedToComparison > 1" ng-click="comparisonQuery()" class="button-text ng-hide">Gå til sammenlign</span>
                        <span ng-hide="addedToComparison > 1" class="button-text">Vælg min. 2 selskaber</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ngIf: insuranceMatch.hasmemberrequirements -->
        <!-- ngIf: insuranceMatch.discountItemCount >0 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for this question. :) I see so many selenium questions that lack attempts to find elements, the code required to initialize the web driver, and the necessary HTML structure Selenium is working with. Your question has all 3. I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Haha, thanks! Thanks to SO I learned how to ask good questions :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

`basicprice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//div[@class="main-price"]')[1])`

`discountedprice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//div[@class="discount-price"]')[1]);`

`selvrisiko = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(.//div[@class="deductible-price"]')[1]);`

`print(basicprice.get_attribute("value"))`

`print(discountedprice.get_attribute("value"))`

`print(selvrisiko.get_attribute("value"))`
print this all `webelement` and you will get the result.

Comment: I believe there's a minor bug in the XPATHs, the start "(." seems to give me a syntax error. i removed them and checking if it works now

Comment: basicprice = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@basicprice='3459']")[0].get_attribute("value") - gave me a list index out of range. Testing with [0] now

Comment: BTW this code seems to be very specific to one value, if the value would change, as it does with insurance, I would need to change it manually as well, in order for the script to identify the e.g. basicprice.

Comment: The [1] seems to give me index out of range error. Testing [0] again with updated code

Comment: You said you have 17 of these thats why I have added index. In selenium it starts with index[1] not [0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201663/discussion-between-pratik-and-doomdaam).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all with simple css selectors:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
resultatside = driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/resultatside")
prices = get_car_insurance()
basic_price = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[basicprice]"))).get_attribute(
        "basicprice")
discounted_price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[discountedprice]").get_attribute("discountedprice")
selvrisiko = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[selvrisiko]").get_attribute("selvrisiko")

print(basic_price, discounted_price, selvrisiko)
```

Your code have is completely should be revised.
Code below does nothing:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait
```

In code below `resultatside` is None - nothing, `driver.get` return None:

```
resultatside = driver.get("https://forsikringsguiden.dk/#!/bilforsikring/resultatside")
```

Comment: Testing this, just a sec.

Comment: Gives me 999999 in result. Close enough

Comment: What do you mean?